# Linq.js scoping

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I am stuck with the following situation. I have a select statement which uses a function in the current scope `me`. How do I go about putting `me` into the select function?

```
var me = this;
var results = Enumerable
              .from(jsonData) 
              .select('x,i=>{abbr:me.transform(x), name:x}')
              .toArray(); //me.transform(x) will hit error
```

'me' is an instance of a dynamically generated object, and `me.transform(x)` uses other dependencies in 'me' to work as well. That means I cannot make 'me.transform()' global function.

---

EDIT

```
var me = this;
var results = Enumerable
              .from(jsonData) 
              .select(function(x,i){
                  return {abbr:me.transform(x), name:x};
              }).toArray();
```

Actually, this modification will work, however, I would like to find out the how to make the shortcut syntax work.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is project your objects to a composite object containing both the item in the collection and the object you want to introduce into the query.

You can use this `Capture` function to capture the variables:

```
function Capture(bindings, name) {
    var benumerable = Enumerable.From(bindings),
        itemname = name || 'Item';
    return function (e) {
        return e.Select(function (item) {
            return benumerable.Concat(Enumerable.Return({ Key: itemname, Value: item }))
                .ToObject("$.Key", "$.Value");
        });
    };
}
```

Use it in a `Let` binding.

```
var query = Enumerable.From(data)
    .Let(Capture({ Me: me }))
    .Select("{ abbr: $.Me.transform($.Item), name: $.Item }")
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Is this what you mean?

```
var me = this;
var results = Enumerable
          .from(jsonData) 
          .select('x,i=>{abbr:' + me.transform(x) + ', name:x}')
          .toArray(); //me.transform(x) will hit error
```

Comment: Whats in the variable 'me'? Is it just a string? What is its purpose?

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work, because you drag the parameter (x) out, and x now comes from nowhere out of the quoted 'x,i=>...' context. I guess the trick is more specific to how Linq.js forms its shortcut syntax. see my edit please.